# MutationObserver on array of elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

So, say I'm looping through the DOM and hiding all `<img>` elements on a page that contain a specific ID/Class string e.g.

```
var strings = ['[id*="example"]','[class*="example"]'];
... 
var MyObject = {
    "getAll": Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(strings.join())),
...
```

On pages like Facebook, content is loaded dynamically, so new images aren't automatically hidden.

I'm trying to use a `MutationObserver` to check when there are any new  elements that match this array, but there is a problem.

```
var observe = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // hide all these newly found imgs somehow
    });
});
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observe.observe(MyObject.getAll, config);
observe.disconnect();
```

For some reason, I receive the error:

```
notfounderror: failed to execute 'observe' on 'mutationobserver': the provided node was null.
```

Even though `MyObject.getAll` is an array with loads of nodes inside?

Basically, I want to check if any newly loaded/visible element matches my `documentSelectorAll('[id*="example"],[class*="example"]')` array via MutationObserver and then I can take the appropriate action by hiding it etc.

Comment: you need to observe.observe() a dom node, not an array. loop and observe each one, or observe a common parent element. you also seem to disconnect it right away, so it will never have a chance to do much of anything even if you pass it an element...

Comment: @dandavis should I use document.body as the selector then? I don't want to search the array as it just contains all the elements that match my queryselector, i'd rather compare/add these new elements that match the queryselector to the array if it makes sense.

Comment: the body would work, but you might be able to get more specific to cut-down noise. i would just watch the container for any insertions, and run my doc.qSA() from inside the mutation event, ignoring the _mutations_ change list it generates for you, but still using the event for timing the check.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, only issue is that trying to run the query selector inside completely crashes Chrome :/ For some reason facebook has like a thousand mutations when you load it

Comment: the number should not matter if you don't iterate the mutations. if the callback is called too much, clear and set a timeout in the callback, pointing to another callback, with an interval of say, 100. that way, it can't run more than 10/sec.